# endpoints in xts using R

Tags: r, xts, endpoints, posixct

I am trying to figure out how `endpoints` selects the times when my data is only weakly regular: that is, some observations are missing.  I have 1 minute returns with some minutes missing and I am trying to convert to 5 minute intervals.  How will `endpoints` decide which times to keep?  The call I use is:

```
endpoints(ret_1_min_xts, k=5, "minutes")
```

My series looks like this, for example:

```
1986-02-04 09:32:00 1
1986-02-04 09:33:00 2
1986-02-04 09:34:00 3
1986-02-04 09:35:00 4
1986-02-04 09:36:00 5
1986-02-04 09:37:00 6
1986-02-04 09:38:00 7
1986-02-04 09:39:00 8
1986-02-04 09:40:00 9
1986-02-04 09:41:00 10
1986-02-04 09:42:00 11
1986-02-04 09:45:00 12
...
```

with the call to `endpoints` returning:

```
1986-02-04 09:34:00
1986-02-04 09:39:00 
1986-02-04 09:42:00 
1986-02-04 09:49:00
1986-02-04 09:54:00
...
```

I am trying to look at the source code of `endpoints` but it seems that the function is in C and is called via `.Call`; am i understanding that correctly?  if someone could explain the methodology used, that would be very helpful.

Comment: I assume you're looking at the source via the R console because if you look at the source in the tarball, you'll see in the comments exactly what `endpoints` is doing.

Comment: i'm actually looking at the C source code and see that it is doing this: `c(0,which(diff(_x%/%on%/%k+1) != 0),NROW(_x))` . i'm trying to figure out what this actually means though. `_x` are the times, `on` is 60 so this converts the data series to minutes by stripping the seconds portion, and then %/%(5+1) converts this to 5 minute returns by stripping off everything that is not a XX:X5, correct?  then takes the diffs to see which times it should keep. still trying to work out the logic.

Comment: @Alex, I think JoshuaUlrich was referring to the [endpoints.R file](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/xts/R/endpoints.R?view=markup&root=xts)

Comment: at first i was looking at the .R file, but then i found the C source code on R-Forge and looked at the .c file. the thing in the last comment posted here comes from the comments in the .c file. i think i have a handle on what's going on now though! thanks guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as answered in the comments above and taken directly from the endpoints.c source code, the function returns this:

```
c(0,which(diff(_x%/%on%/%k+1) != 0),NROW(_x))
```

where `_x = .index(my_xts)`

what does this actually do? with respect to my call of the `endpoints` function:

the stuff inside `diff` first removes the seconds and then moves things into k minute increments (all this using integer division).  `diff` then simply notes the points where you change to the next increment and `which` returns those points where the increment occurs. in effect this simply returns the last point in each 5 minute interval (k=5 in my call)

Comment: To copy/paste the comment in the source code as an answer seems hardly sufficient.  You yourself said you found that comment but still didn't understand it.  Why not include an explanation of the code in your answer?

Comment: btw, i thought this particular comment line in R was particularly clever by the package authors